# import threading not working python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, installation

I am trying to use threading in an upcoming project but I can't get it working.  I've tried running the 2nd example on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm, which I imagine is working code, but I get the error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/threads/threading.py", line 3, in <module>
    import threading2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\threading2\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from threading import _active,_DummyThread
  File "C:\Python27\threads\threading.py", line 8, in <module>
    class myThread (threading2.Thread):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
```

Whats going on? It seems like there is no module named threading.  I've looked everywhere to find it.  Does anyone know where I can find this module and how to install it?

Comment: As a side note, I'm not sure a tutorial that refers to Python 2.4 as "new" is the best place to start…

Comment: Have you put your own code inside `C:\Python27`? That's not a good idea.

Comment: `threading2`? Never heard of that one before.

Comment: @user2357112: A quick PyPI search [turns it up](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/threading2). Apparently it's awesomer. :)

Comment: I don't know why there would be any references to it in the standard library `threading` module. It looks like there might be some sort of circular import bug going on. EDIT: That's not the standard library `threading` module. Putting code in the Python installation folder and naming it the same as a standard library module are both bad ideas.

Comment: @user2357112: As Matthias realized, the standard library `threading` module isn't being loaded at all, because the OP's script is named `threading.py`.

Comment: The right way to deal with this is to name the script something like `threading_test.py` or `my_example.py`. (People often avoid the problem by naming the scripts without the `.py` extension, but this is a little hacky on Unix, and much more so on Windows.)

Comment: @user2357112 I thought threading didn't exist under modules so I tried to replace it with an awesomer module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You called your own file `threading` and now you're importing your own script and that's not what you want. Please do not use the names of existing packages/modules for your own scripts.

When the code in `threading2.py` tries to `import threading`, Python first looks for an already-imported module with that name. If that fails, it looks through each location in `sys.path` for a file named `threading.py` that it can load. Normally, it will find the one in the standard library. But if you have a file named `threading.py` in the same location as the script—or if it's the name of the script itself—Python will find that one first, and load it instead.

Also, don't save your own scripts in the folder where Python is installed.

Comment: That's probably the right answer, but you need to explain it…

Comment: Oh, I missed the circular import. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Yup thank you I probably should have picked up on that good answer